# Repositioning and resizing when i change the size of my frame

Tags: coordinate-systems

> **Moderator's Note:** This question is cross-posted on [gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/57378).

I am trying to write a game.

When someone resizes the window of my game, I need all the graphics i have drawn on the screen to reposition correctly so that the ratio of the graphics' width and height remain correct and that the new position determined by x and y, have been adjusted for the new size screen.

In the following image, the top left corner is 0,0... all coordinates / widths / heights are measured from this point.

[image]

What do I need to do to x, y, width and height from the variable width and height of my screen in order to keep this aspect ratio correct?

**SIDE NOTE: the aspect ratio of the screen will always be 16:9!**

Comment: All you have to do is to multiply the coordinates by the scaling factor.

Comment: This seems like it might be better over on gamedev.SE; I've suggested to the mods that it be moved.

Comment: Note, this question has been crossposted to [gamedev.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57378/repositioning-and-resizing-when-i-change-the-size-of-my-window). Crossposting without at least mentioning that you are crossposting is considered rude and begs to have redundancy in answers across the sites.

Comment: @mixedmath - No, what is rude is that you assume i am doing this without due care and maliciousness. I have asked in two places because this is both a math question and a code question. Here i get a formula i can understand, in the other site I get a bit of code to help me see what others do. Please do not assume things, it's extremely unfair. Doing what i have done has meant i have an accurate solution to my problem and i truly understand the entirety of the solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an idea, assign each pixel as follows: 
$$
x_1=\left\lfloor x_0\cdot \frac{1376}{1920}\right\rfloor \\
y_1=\left\lfloor y_0\cdot \frac{768}{1080}\right\rfloor
$$

where $(x_0,y_0)$ are the large screen coordinates, and $(x_1,y_1)$ are the small screen coordinates.

Obviously, there are more pixels in the bigger screen than in the small screen, so some pixels map to the same location.  In those cases, you need some way of choosing which pixel to take.

This method will change the proportions very slightly.

Comment: Rightt, let me run this through my code.. hang on :)